# Etat HTTP 404 - /mvc/traitementTwo.jsp - spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i m trying to capitalize the name entered in the form and display it

The Controller :

```
package yo;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage(){
        return "helloworld";
       }

    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(){
        return"form";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/traitement")
    public String processForm(){
        return"traitement";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/traitementTwo")
    public String caps(HttpServletRequest request,Model model){

        String theName=request.getParameter("s");
        String result="YO "+theName.toUpperCase();
        model.addAttribute("message", result);
        return"helloworld";
    }

}
```

form.jsp:

```
<body>
hello   <form action="traitementTwo.jsp" method="GET">

    <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="who are u ?" />

    <input type="submit"/>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

helloworld.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
    the time on the server is <%= new String("Hello World").toUpperCase() %>
<br>


    The message :${message}

</body>
</html>
```

spring-mvcdemo-servlet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="yo" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>mvc</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Output :

Etat HTTP 404 - /mvc/traitementTwo.jsp
type Rapport d''état

message /mvc/traitementTwo.jsp

description La ressource demandée n''est pas disponible.

---

Apache Tomcat/8.0.36

Comment: how did you config the *view-controller* of spring mvc?

Comment: take a look i post it

Comment: I answered your previous question.. it seems now you're having another issue? Rather than unmark my answer and change this to a completely different question, you should create a new question for this.

Comment: Do *not* re-purpose a post to ask a new question. You'll have to create a new question post instead. By altering this post, you invalidate all the work the answerers put into giving you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may not have setup your web.xml properly to create the servlet contexts etc.

Refer to the following project: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-and-list-example/

It has the following structure within src->main->webapp

/- web.xml

/- mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

/ pages (directory within which to store jsp pages)

Otherwise please post your webapp or spring boot config to confirm that you've set it up correctly.

Comment: take a look i post it

Answer (score 0):

you have use Spring-MVC to develop , but you don't have the Spring MVC configure XML file. you should create A spring-mvc.xml to configure some message about spring mvc

Comment: take a look i post it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I know what the issue is.. in your form.jsp you had:

```
<form action="traitementTwo.jsp" method="GET">
```

should be:

```
<form action="traitementTwo" method="GET">
```

Comment: @AymanR'bati are you sure.. ? I actually put your code on my environment, deployed it and ran into the same issue.  Then I changed it to traitementTwo and it worked...